# Override pipeline definition variable in pipeline run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have variable VERSIONNEW where I store new value in first step of pipeline, variable is updated in new run(value is 1039), but in same pipeline run VERSIONNEW has still old value(value is 1035). Is there a way how to override value in same run?

```
$url =     "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/Release/definitions/$($env:RELEASE_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0-preview.3"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

# Update an existing variable named VERSIONNEW to its new value 1039
$pipeline.variables.VERSIONNEW.value = "1039"

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType     "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'VERSIONNEW' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.VERSIONNEW.value
write-host "=========================================================="
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your PowerShell script, you are changing the variable value in Pipeline definition.

In this case, the value will not be replaced in current run. It will take effect in the next pipeline run.

> Is there a way how to override value in same run?

You can use logging command to update the variable value. [SetVariable: Initialize or modify the value of a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)

For example:

```
steps:
- powershell: 'echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VERSIONNEW;]1039"'
```

It will update the value in the same pipeline run next tasks.

Comment: and is way how to use this variable also in another stages?

Comment: @WMindian. You can refer to this doc: [Use outputs in a different stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage)